# Why edits via the Developer Tools to the website not get saved?

Tags: devtools

Why when changing the CSS in the dev tools only temporarily have effects and not after the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you have modified just a local copy. To learn how your browser works: [Inside look at modern web browser](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/09/inside-browser-part1)

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the website in developer console or inspect elements it will be saved until you reload the page